# Bootstrap Datetimepicker Trigger "dp.change" on Class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) package for my datepicker. I'm initiating the plugin like this (CS):

```js
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    language: 'en'
    })
.on('dp.change', (e) =>{
    console.log 'this'
})
```

The datepicker works fine, but the dp.change event is not triggered, anyone can explain why?

**[DIRTY SOLUTION]**

For now I'm using something like this, very ugly solution though:

```js
$('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').on("click","td.day", () => {
    date = $('.datepicker input[type=text]').val()
    $('.datepicker p').find('span').text(date)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

The documentations 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
Gives you an example on how to do this. (Just tested it and if you copy+paste the code, it will work fine.)

```
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
//do your action here
        });
```

The ID of the jquery selector, you put the element you activated the datepicker for (i.e. initiated it like:

```
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
```

) 
 Let me know if it didn't work out for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the `DOM` `ID` of the element, you may listen to events on the `document`:

```
$(document).on('dp.change', function (e) {
  // here `e` is an event itself.
  // So, `e.target` should be a DOM element of the input field.
  if ($(e.target).data('object') === 'calendar1') {
      console.log('calendar1 just changed');
  } else {
      console.log('nope, we are waiting for calendar1 changes only');
  }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It's should be easy to get a current input element. See code I changed with comments. So to listen to specific calendar, I would add some flag to a input node and then check that flag in the event listener in the code above. A bit hackish but should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old thread to comment but I think the answers are a bit confusing. to get the selected date you can use

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function(e){
//To get moment object
console.log(e.date);
//To format date into DD/MM/YYYY
console.log(e.date.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I just faced the same problem and I did solve it by adding change event to the input.

```
$("body").on("change dp.change", "#your_selector", function(event){
     var date = $("#your_selector").data("datetimepicker").getDate();
     console.log(date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to add [moment.js](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment.js) (before the datetimepicker.js) in your page. Add the script and it should work just fine.

Comment: It is there, and im sure it is loaded BEFORE the datetimepicker

Comment: Getting any error in the console?? Press F12 in chrome and ctrl+shift+I in firefox and check

Comment: Is it because I add it to the class instead id?But I have tested with id and it won't work either

Comment: No, both class and ID are inside jquery wrapper and both are treated in the same way(as jQuery object)

Comment: Have you checked this link ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500662/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-events-not-firing-up

Comment: Seems like a cache issue.. Clean browser cache or simply press ctrl+f5 to refresh the page