# Trigger an event when selecting a date/time with datetime-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am currently using [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#no-icon-input-field-only) datetimepicker in my code (No Icon (input field only)) and I need to trigger a function once a date-time is selected. 
I tried using several jQuery functions but I would get different errors, here are the ones I used:

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert("date chosen");                                              
    }
});
```

I get this error

> TypeError: option onClose is not recognized!

and a similar one for `onSelect`,
and when I use `datepicker instead`

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datepicker({
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert("date chosen");                                              
    }
});
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

ps: I am using jQuery 1.11.3 and running the code with firefox.

Edit: problem was solved with [`dp.change`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398028/bootstrap-datetimepicker-trigger-dp-change-on-class)

Comment: Did you check the Events tab on that page? https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/ - specifically the dpchange https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange

Comment: I just checked it, that was really helpful , thanks :)

Comment: @heba post an answer (an accept it) describing the working solution instead of editing your own question to add the solution.

Comment: @VincenzoC my answer gets converted to a comment because it's too short I guess

Comment: @heba there is no automatic conversion of answer into comments, but very short answer are not very useful, they tend to attract downvotes and sometimes get deleted. I suggested to post a good answer (e.g. explanation of the solution, docs links and/or quotes, working code sample etc), I've posted an answer to show an example of something that is not too short with an example of how to use `dp.change` in your use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eonasdan datetimepicker has no `onClose` option, you can add an handler for [`dp.change`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange) event:

> Fired when the date is changed.
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> e = {
>   date, //date the picker changed to. Type: moment object (clone)
>   oldDate //previous date. Type: moment object (clone) or false in the event of a null
> }
> ```

Here a live sample:

```js
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker()
  .on('dp.change', function(e){
    if(e.date){
      console.log('Date chosen: ' + e.date.format() );
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```