# How to get raw date data from Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Control is an input field that I define. Whenever I click on the control, it will open the datetimepicker and append whatever date I choose onto the control for example 11/30/2015 ( Display value )

Javascript

```
control.datetimepicker({
    pickTime:false,
    language: en
});
```

Is there a way that I could obtain raw date (correct me if I am wrong) like this:

```
Wed Feb 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
```

As different language will have different display date value, it will be great if I am able to obtain raw date to do processing into my server.

Answer (score 1):

I had found the answer in here:
[Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker events not firing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500662/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-events-not-firing-up)

The version I use is: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Therefore to get the date obj stuff I can use this:

```
control.datetimepicker({
     pickTime: false,
     language: en
  }).on("dp.change", function(e) {
  var date = e.date, 
  dDate = date._d, // e.g Wed Feb 06 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time 
  dateFormat = date._f; // e.g MM-DD-YYYY
  // Append to attribute
  control.attr('dateFormat', dateFormat);
});
```

I can then use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to format it like this:

```
value = $('#' + fieldDefinition.Name).val();
var dateFormat = $('#' + fieldDefinition.Name).attr('dateformat');
value = moment(value, dateFormat).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
// OR - Depending on what your server accept
value = moment(value, dateFormat).format();
```

Therefore I can display different date/datetime format/separator according to locale on my controls and also ensuring that they are formatted to the whatever I want. In my case is [XML date / datetime format](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
  $("selectorForDP").data().DateTimePicker.date()._d;

this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Keep in mind this will most likely only work for english formatted date.

Comment: @rouby it works as long as he does not change format explicitly via datetimepicker's option.

Comment: More or less what I said.. ?

Comment: @Rouby I am looking for a way that can work for all kinds of locale display date. Which means if in US MM/DD/YYYY or Dutch DD-MM-YYYY should be able to return the date object/raw data. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rouby Yes. I found the solution for the control and yes I am also using [momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com). I posted an answer for this. Thanks mate for your help.