# on change event does not trigger when date change in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have input type text where I have initalized data and value from viewbag.

I am trying to handle and date change event when date changed But its not trigger the change event.

I am using bootstrap.min.js, moment.min.js bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js javascript library.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" style="display:inline-block;width:120px" 
    id="openItemFromDate" 
    data-begindate="@ViewBag.InitalDates[0]" 
    value="@ViewBag.InitalDates[0]">



   var beginDate = new Date();
   var endDate = new Date();    

    $('#openItemFromDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        icons: {
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    });
    $('#openItemToDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        icons: {
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        }
    });


    $('#openItemFromDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        beginDate = e.date.format("MM/DD/YYYY");

        $(this).data('begindate', beginDate);

    })

    $('#openItemToDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {
        endDate = e.date.format("MM/DD/YYYY");

        $(this).data('endDate', endDate);

    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker events not firing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500662/bootstrap-3-datetimepicker-events-not-firing-up)

Comment: try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: Guys I added the code in when document.ready  function. It worked. Thank you.